# Android how to send SMS using source number through SmsManager?

Tags: java, android, telephonymanager, smsmanager

I am trying to send SMS from my application using SmsManager.
Here is my code:-

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(destPhoneNumber, srcPhoneNo, message, sentPI,
            deliveredPI);
```

Here srcPhoneNo means sms service code number.

But i want to specify my source number from which no i want to send sms.

How can i do it.Need some help?

Comment: Wht's the problem you are facing actually?

Comment: i want to use source no for sending sms. but here no support for this.

Comment: using SmsManager.sendTextMessage(destPhoneNumber, srcPhoneNo, message, sentPI,deliveredPI); only send sms from 1st sim by default. but i want to specify my mobile mo.

Comment: you can put null instead to use the current default SMSC

Comment: null means default. i don't want to send sms from default no.